# How to change mlp (multilayer perceptron) loss function in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, mlp

What is default loss function in MLPRegressor? MSE?
How to change mlp (multilayer perceptron) loss function in sklearn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html):

> This model optimizes the **squared error** using LBFGS or stochastic gradient descent.

I don't think you can change the loss function. For other loss functions it would be better to use [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) or [Keras](https://keras.io/).

Comment: In case it isn't obvious: the `MLPClassifier` optimizes log-loss. So scikit-learn MLPs support one loss for classification and another for regression. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html